# Moving a pair of studs 4 inches

Tags: framing, remodeling

We are trying to put in an interior window between a room and an addition to the home that was added later. We cut out a hole in the drywall between the studs of the original room. However the studs of the addition are flush with the existing wall and are overlapping where the window will go by about 3 inches on each side. I was wondering what the best way to go about moving the studs would be. Would I need to put in a header?

Thanks for any help.

Edit: Adding a picture.  [image]

Comment: Did the wall used to be an exterior wall?

Comment: The wall we would want to move the studs on is in the addition. We would not move the studs on the old exterior wall.

Comment: I guess I'm not clear about the "room and an addition to the home that was added later" part.  Was this ever an exterior wall?  The reason I ask is that if it was an exterior wall at any point it's likely to be load bearing.

Comment: Sorry, it is definitely a load bearing wall. I added a photo for clarity. The light 2x4 flush with the old siding is the one we want to shift so that the drywall currently cut out will be the opening.

Comment: You might be able to remove that stud and that one stud only without negatively affecting stability, but do so at your own risk.  I would personally move the window the other way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you aren't changing the framing of the former exterior wall at all, you can basically do whatever is most convenient for the "wall" on the addition side.  Flat studded walls are not going to be load bearing, so you don't need a header.  The 2x4s on that side are basically only there to provide a place for the sheerock to attach.  Basically you'll be putting in 2x4 furring strips around the hole.  About the only thing that you should try to do is to attach whatever you put in to something solid (i.e. other framing) so the drywall around the window doesn't crack.

Comment: We wouldn't be moving the studs on the former exterior wall. It is the studs for the room addition. The confusing part for me is that they lay flush with the old exterior of the house. So i'm not really sure how to do the header. The piece of wood behind the circular cut out is the one I need to move. Sorry if i'm not making sense.

Comment: @goodtothet23 - See edits. No header, just something to attach the sheetrock to.